# c# refactoring with linq query

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to improve my linq syntax coding and i was wondering if anyone could show me a better way of writing this code below.Question is taken from leetcode https://leetcode.com/problems/kids-with-the-greatest-number-of-candies/.
Thanks

```
        public static IList<bool> KidsWithCandies(int[] candles, int extraCandies)
        {
           var kidCandle = candles.Select(x => x+ extraCandies);
           var con = new List<bool>();
            foreach(var kid in kidCandle)
            {
                if (kid >= candles.Max())
                    con.Add(true);
                else
                    con.Add(false);
            }

           return con;
        }
```

https://leetcode.com/problems/kids-with-the-greatest-number-of-candies/

Comment: ``int max = candles.Max(); List<bool> con = candles.Select(x => x + extraCandies>= max).ToList();``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Linq also does looping but just a syntacitc sugar, but we can write a `Select` for the foreach. So the code :

```
var con = new List<bool>();
foreach(var kid in kidCandle)
{
    if (kid >= candles.Max())
        con.Add(true);
    else
        con.Add(false);
}
```

can be replaced with:

```
public static IList<bool> KidsWithCandies(int[] candles, int extraCandies)
{
   var kidCandle = candles.Select(x => x+ extraCandies);
   var maxCandles = candles.Max();
   var con = kidCandle.Select(kid => (kid >= maxCandles)).ToList();
   return con;
}
```

even the whole method could be written like:

```
public static IList<bool> KidsWithCandies(int[] candles, int extraCandies)
{
    var maxCandles = candles.Max();
    return candles.Select(x => x+ extraCandies)
                 .Select(kid => (kid >= maxCandles)).ToList();
}
```

Now more simpler:

```
public static IList<bool> KidsWithCandies(int[] candles, int extraCandies)
{
   var maxCandles = candles.Max();
   var con = candles.Select(kid => (kid + extraCandies >= maxCandles)).ToList();
   return con;
}
```

we can even avoid `var` :

```
 public static IList<bool> KidsWithCandies(int[] candles, int extraCandies)
 {
     var maxCandles = candles.Max();     
     return candles.Select(kid => (kid + extraCandies >= maxCandles)).ToList();
 }
```

Comment: You don't need to `? true : false` something that's already a boolean. It's kind of like doing `bool foo = true ? true : false;`

Comment: Or `public static IList<bool> KidsWithCandies(int[] candles, int extraCandies) => candles.Select(kid => (kid + extraCandies >= candles.Max()));`

Comment: Current query has complexity O(n^2), due to calculating `Max` in every `Select` call. It is strongly advised to move `Max` calculation to dedicated variable.